# HttpClient.GetAsync executes only 2 requests at a time?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

Why is HttpClient.GetAsync()/PostAsync()/SendAsync() etc only scheduling 2 requests at a time?

I tested this in the following way:

I have an async GET method that waits without blocking for 10 seconds before responding.

```
public async Task<string> Get()
{
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine($"{guid}: {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}: start");
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine($"{guid}: {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}: end");
    return "hello";
}
```

If I call the endpoint from Chrome by refreshing multiple times I see they all execute as soon as I hit refresh, and I receive the responses 10 seconds later:

```
39a20541-a2d6-4cd0-99cd-db0987e273e9: 5:32:44 PM: start
8326d829-28a6-48a2-9874-6506b79488af: 5:32:44 PM: start
aecfbb10-266c-46f8-be3b-bfc2fadf0775: 5:32:44 PM: start
78932f53-37a5-4f26-a56f-b3196256e1cf: 5:32:44 PM: start
39a20541-a2d6-4cd0-99cd-db0987e273e9: 5:32:54 PM: end
8326d829-28a6-48a2-9874-6506b79488af: 5:32:54 PM: end
aecfbb10-266c-46f8-be3b-bfc2fadf0775: 5:32:54 PM: end
78932f53-37a5-4f26-a56f-b3196256e1cf: 5:32:54 PM: end
```

But if I make calls using this code in a console application:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
for (var ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++)
{
    client.GetAsync("http://localhost:50621/api/default");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

I see that `Console.ReadKey();` is reached immediately, but the requests are executed two by two - it makes 2 requests, then waits 10 seconds to finish, then another 2, another 10 seconds, etc., even though all 10 have been supposedly scheduled.

```
80546610-c20e-4ff1-b6e5-0fe1688e8803: 5:39:10 PM: start
9bbbb707-9ea7-44da-9d5b-03efc3c4aa47: 5:39:10 PM: start
80546610-c20e-4ff1-b6e5-0fe1688e8803: 5:39:20 PM: end
9bbbb707-9ea7-44da-9d5b-03efc3c4aa47: 5:39:20 PM: end
a146c3ca-a0d2-4588-b60b-156f1febc944: 5:39:20 PM: start
b71bc77f-9bdb-4aa6-936e-c702eb7d49eb: 5:39:20 PM: start
....
```

So why aren't all the requests made immediately? Does HttpClient have some sort of a limit on pending requests?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`HttpClient`, as well as other http-related classes, uses service points for http connection management:

> The ServicePoint class handles connections to an Internet resource
>   based on the host information passed in the resource's Uniform
>   Resource Identifier (URI). The initial connection to the resource
>   determines the information that the ServicePoint object maintains,
>   which is then shared by all subsequent requests to that resource.

There is `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` static property, which controls default maximum number of concurrent connections allowed for `ServicePoint` object, and by default this property has value 2.

That means that by default you can only have 2 concurrent connections to given host. To "fix" this - increase that number to some bigger value, usually somewhere at startup of your application.